# Drawing Bar char in python using Enthought Canopy

Tags: python, canopy

I need help in drawing bar chart for my data using Enthought Canopy. I written a python program which display number of medals won by each country.

```
Country                          Medals
-------------------------------------
United States                    243
Russia                           187
Australia                        183
Germany                          118
Netherlands                       79
```

My resultant list consists of country name and total medals. Now I want to draw a bar chart using this data. I am not understanding the how the "bar" method works in canopy. Can any one help me with this.

Here is the draw chart method I want to create.
def drawChart(medalList):

Answer (score 1):

Canopy comes with Matplotlib, a package for plotting data easily. You should look at its bar chart functionalities: http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html
Your problem seems substantially simpler that this example though since you don't have error bars to deal with. You should end up with something similar to:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5
menMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)

ind = np.arange(N)  # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, menMeans, width, color='r')

womenMeans = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
rects2 = ax.bar(ind+width, womenMeans, width, color='y')

ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(ind+width)
ax.set_xticklabels( ('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5') )

ax.legend( (rects1[0], rects2[0]), ('Men', 'Women') )

plt.show()
```

HTH,